# YUI Datatable Width

Tags: datatable, html-table, width, yui

This may seem like a basic question, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the table width to 100% on a YUI datatable.

I tried doing

```
#dtContainer {
    width: 100%;
}

#dtContainer table {
    width: 100%
}
```

but none of these approaches work.

To clarify, I am trying to set the datatable width to 100% when the table is empty and the empty message is displayed.

The generated table is an HTML table; so, I thought this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the solution is really simple:

```
.yui-dt table
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In that case you should select the answer from Matt Calderaro as the correct answer, not your own answer that you didn't use.

Answer (score 6):

Dont use .yui-dt table { width:100%;} , It doesn't appear to set the column widths correctly.  Use myDataTable.setAttributes({width:"100%"},true); after table render

Comment: worked for me. also added the following on postRender so the header and body would alight right:
     $("div.yui-dt-hd").css('width', 'auto');
     $("div.yui-dt-bd").css('width', 'auto');

Comment: If it doesn't work, use `setAttrs` instead of `setAttributes` (YUI3).

Answer (score 1):

this is an ugly solution. but it works

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
setTimeout('document.getElementById("NAME OF CONTAINER DIV").childNodes[1].style.width
= "100%"',1000);
};
</script>
```

the problem is applying the style pre render is pointless, the javascript is building the table, post render is all I could get to work.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use your implementation, but it did point me in the right direction.

I basically used the YUI Dom method setAttribute to set the size on methods that triggers the render() event on the YUI datatable.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this little style tag works magic:

```
 .yui-dt table { width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain aspect ratio across various screens with different resolutions, I had to manually set the column width as percentages that summed up to 100%.

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* YUI Individual Column Width */        
    #dvAutoWidthList .yui-dt-col-Col1{width: 35%;}
    #dvAutoWidthList .yui-dt-col-Col2{width: 10%;}
    #dvAutoWidthList .yui-dt-col-Col3{width: 15%;}
    #dvAutoWidthList .yui-dt-col-Col4, .yui-dt-col-Col5, .yui-dt-col-Col6, .yui-dt-col-Col7 {width: 10%;}

</style>
```

PS: Might not be the best way to do this, but it solved my problem!

Kwex.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataTable = new Y.DataTable(
          {
            columns: cols,
            data: remoteData,
            width: '100%',             
          }
        ).render('#dataTable ');
```

This should do the trick. Worked for me AUI 2.5.1